# Write a Project Variable from a Modeler result attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am trying to set a Project Variable with QGIS Modeler with values as the modeler calculates them.  In this case I am trying to get the calculated area from a process "Fire_Area" written to a project variable that can be input into the map sheets or atlas etc.  Everything works but the write to the variable fails.  See attached images.

[image: Modeler]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since field calculator will evaluate the expression for each feature, it seems like you want to assign a kind of dynamic value to a project variable name.

You can't that way, because **custom project variables accepts only string literal values**. In fact, they will be stored as a string in the project file.

You probably don't need it, but **you could set the expression text, and evaluate it in any other context of the expressions builder**, as long as the built-ins you use in the expression are valid in that context.

---

For example, `@feature` built-in variable and `$area` function are valid in a field calculator context.

You can fill a field value with the ellipsoidal area of each feature's geometry (regardless of its crs) with:

```
$area
```

For the planimetric area (dependent on its crs) you can:

```
area( geometry( @feature))
```

Although simpler:

```
area( @geometry)
```

In all those cases, you are assigning a value to a property (for example the *fire_area* property) of each feature, by filling its field. This is what is generally done when you want a "dynamic value based on each feature".

But nothing prevents you from set the literal text of the expression in a project variable called, for instance, *fire_area_expr*:

```
'$area'
```

And then you can evaluate it in a field calculator:

```
eval( @fire_area_expr)
```

Fortunately, both built-ins (`@feature` and `$area`) can also be used in the context of atlas page filters, or labels of an atlas-controlled layout. Therefore that project variable can also be used there, in the same way.

---

In any case, if you want to set a custom project variable from a model output, it has to be a text. It can be a text input of the model, or an expression algorithm output returning a text. And it can be then evaluated as a expression in a context.

---

If you already filled the *fire_area* field of each feature with the area value, you could also use:

```
attribute( @feature, 'fire_area')
```

Or simpler:

```
"fire_area"
```

---

The *with_variable* function creates a fleeting variable, which value can store absolutely any type of data:

```
with_variable(
 'fire_area_var', --the variable name
 $area, --the expression to compute its value
 @fire_area_var --an expression calling the variable value by its name
)
```